# remove strings pattern with sed/awk/perl

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want make this substitution:

```
"name1"."name2"()="name3"."name4"
```

Using Sed I' ve tried:

```
sed -e 's/\"[[:alpha:]]*\"\.\"[[:alpha:]]*\"\=\"[[:alpha:]]*\"\.\"[[:alpha:]]*\"//g'
```

### with no success.

The solution suggested by NeronLeVelu

```
echo '"NAME1"."NAME2"="NAME3"."NAME4"'|sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"="[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"//g'
```

It works using a single occurrence:

But in a more complex strings doesn' t works ... :-( 
On  --AIX 6 1 ---

```
>cat /tmp/bbbb 
case when "D"."COD_COMP"="B"."COD_COMP" AND "D"."COD_CNL"="B"."COD_CNL" AND "D"."COD_PUN"="B"."COD_PUN" AND "D"."COD_UNTA"="B"."COD_UNTA" 

>cat /tmp/bbbb|sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"="[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"//g' case when "D"."COD_COMP"="B"."COD_COMP" AND "D"."COD_CNL"="B"."COD_CNL" AND "D"."COD_PUN"="B"."COD_PUN" AND "D"."COD_UNTA"="B"."COD_UNTA" –
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: The word `pattern` is ambiguous, don't use it. Are you talking about replacing a regexp with a string or a string with a string or something else?

Comment: Tanks Ed for your reply . Im trying to substitute a (long) string containing some occurrences of regexp with a fixed string (or NULL // in sed to delete the occurences) each time I find an occurence.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]_]*"\."[[:alnum:]_]*"\(()\)\{0,1\}="[[:alnum:]_]*"\."[[:alnum:]_]*"\([[:space:]]\{1,\}AND[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)\{0,1\}/YourReplacementString/' YourFile
```

- No escape of `"`, `=`
- use `[:alnum:]` instead of `[:alpha:]` due to number inside
- add char like `_-`
- add an optional missing `()`
- add the mandatory `AND` if present

Comment: Thanks Neron.Doesn't work.                                                                                   echo  '"NAME1"."NAME2"="NAME3"."NAME4"'|sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"()="[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"//g'   **"NAME1"."NAME2"="NAME3"."NAME4"**

Comment: on wich system ? test and work on my AIX (posix compliant) and my Red Hat ?  Your echo is missing `()`

Comment: Thanks Neron.It works.                                                                                   echo  '"NAME1"."NAME2"="NAME3"."NAME4"'|sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"="[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"//g'     but without "()"

Comment: But in a more complex strings doesn' t works ... :-(   --AIX 6 1 
--->cat /tmp/bbbb
case when "D"."COD_COMP"="B"."COD_COMP" AND "D"."COD_CNL"="B"."COD_CNL" AND "D"."COD_PUN"="B"."COD_PUN" AND "D"."COD_UNTA"="B"."COD_UNTA" 
>cat /tmp/bbbb|sed -e 's/"[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"="[[:alnum:]]*"\."[[:alnum:]]*"//g'
case when "D"."COD_COMP"="B"."COD_COMP" AND "D"."COD_CNL"="B"."COD_CNL" AND "D"."COD_PUN"="B"."COD_PUN" AND "D"."COD_UNTA"="B"."COD_UNTA"

Comment: your new string is very different of first sample. I adapt the reply